# Populating listview API call

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, android-listview

I'm new to Android and am trying to figure out how to pass a search keyword string "tag" from searchActivity to the API URL below in SearchResult to display in a listview in SearchResult.

I'm having trouble populating the listview -   Am I missing something in my setup or adapter?

SearchActivity.java

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = SearchActivity.class.getName();

private ArrayList<Photo> photos;
private PhotosAdapter photosAdapter;

EditText mSearch;
String searchedTag;
Button goSearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    mSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchField);
    goSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gosearch);

    goSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent result = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, SearchResult.class );
            result.putExtra ( "searchkey", mSearch.getText().toString() );
            startActivity(result);


        }
    });

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

SearchResult.java

```
 public class SearchResult extends Activity {

private ArrayList<Photo> photosSearch;
private PhotoAdapterSearch photosAdapterSearch;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);

    Intent myintent = getIntent();
    String tag = myintent.getStringExtra("searchkey");


    getTags(tag);

}
private void getTags(String tag) {



    photosSearch = new ArrayList<Photo>();

    // Create adapter
    photosAdapterSearch = new PhotoAdapterSearch(this, photosSearch);

    ListView listViewResult = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewResult);
    // Set the adapter
    listViewResult.setAdapter(photosAdapterSearch);

    String TAGGED_IMAGES_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/"+tag+"/media/recent?access_token=55408742.1677ed0.ad911fb2100340d9807ab22162e58dc1";

    new AsycnGet().execute(TAGGED_IMAGES_URL);
}



public class AsycnGet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                builder.append(line);

            return builder.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        if (s != null && s != "") {
            try {
                JSONObject response = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(s).nextValue();
                JSONArray photosJSON = response.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < photosJSON.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject photoJSON = photosJSON.getJSONObject(i);
                    Photo photosearch = new Photo();

                    photosearch.imageUrl = photoJSON.getJSONObject("images").getJSONObject("standard_resolution").getString("url");
                    photosearch.imageHeight = photoJSON.getJSONObject("images").getJSONObject("standard_resolution").getInt("height");


                    photosSearch.add(photosearch);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

PhotoAdapterSearch.Java
    public class PhotoAdapterSearch extends ArrayAdapter {

```
public PhotoAdapterSearch(Context context, List<Photo> photos) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, photos);
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //get photo at position
    final Photo photo = getItem(position);


    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_search, null, false);
    }



    ImageView myImageViewsearch = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagesearch);

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    myImageViewsearch.getLayoutParams().height = displayMetrics.widthPixels;


    myImageViewsearch.setImageResource(0);
    // insert the image using picasso
    int ratio = photo.imageWidth / photo.imageHeight;
    int width = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int height = width / Math.max(1, ratio);
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(photo.imageUrl).resize(0, height).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(myImageViewsearch);


    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your PhotoAdapterSearch code please?

Comment: Also you might want to try calling `photosAdapterSearch.notifyDatasetChanged()` in `onPostExecute` after you add a photo to the array

Comment: the app stopped when I added notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: What exception was thrown?

Answer (score 0):

You give adapter empty list and it builds ListView of 0 items.
If you want adapter to rebuild list (like when you downloaded items to array), you should call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); (I can mistype exact name)

And maybe it will help if you will provide sources of adapter as well.

Comment: adding this caused the app to crash